# Redshift to_timestamp with timezone offset

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have difficulties in converting this timestamp string `2020-09-08T15:30:00+00:00` to a correct UTC time:

If I do this:

```sql
select to_timestamp('2020-09-08T15:30:00+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS');
```

I get `2020-09-08 15:30:00.000000 -04:00`, which is on a wrong timezone.

How can I parse the +00:00 part of the string? I tried `TZ/OF` based on [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html) but they are not allowed to be added:

```
[0A000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: "TZ"/"tz" not supported;
```

, while I'm doing this: `select to_timestamp('2020-09-08T15:30:00+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS+TZ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are trying to convert using to_timestamp, because in your example its already `UTC/GMT` only.

I have used this way in past, I hope it should work for you as well.

```
#below is something saved in IST(+5:30) to GMT
SELECT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('GMT','2020-09-08 15:30:00+05:30');
```

Similarly, it could be converted to US/Newyork timezone.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/New_York','2020-09-08 15:30:00+05:30') ;
```